# mysql subtract one select query from another select query value

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have two mysql table and I have build to select query using this two tables, both query output is a summation of quantity from inventory_transfer_details table. I need to subtract "total_to" from "total_from". please check below is mysql tables.

Inventory_transfer
[image]

inventory_transfer_details
[image]

below is my two queries.

First query:

```
select sum(b.transfer_quantity) as total_to 
from inventory_transfers as a 
join inventory_transfer_details as b on a.id = b.inventory_transfer_id 
where a.status="approved" and b.inventory_or_composite_id = '1' and a.to_warehouse_id = '2'
```

second query:

```
select sum(b.transfer_quantity) as total_from 
from inventory_transfers as a 
join inventory_transfer_details as b on a.id = b.inventory_transfer_id 
where a.status="approved" and b.inventory_or_composite_id = '1' and a.from_warehouse_id = '2'
```

I need to subtract from query transfer_to  to transfer_from

can you have any guide to convert this final query to laravel query?

Comment: Why the repeated references to Laravel?

Comment: @symcbean my main goal is there are two different quantity to subtract from each other

Comment: Why the repeated references to Laravel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can combine those queries and get the difference

```
SELECT
  sum(
    IF(a.to_warehouse_id = '2', b.transfer_quantity, 0)
  ) - sum(
    IF(a.from_warehouse_id = '2', b.transfer_quantity, 0)
  ) as total
FROM
  inventory_transfers AS a
  JOIN inventory_transfer_details AS b ON a.id = b.inventory_transfer_id
WHERE
  a.status = "approved"
  AND b.inventory_or_composite_id = '1'
```

In the laravel query builder, this query might look like

```
DB::table('inventory_transfers as a')
    ->select(DB::raw('sum(IF(a.to_warehouse_id = '2', b.transfer_quantity, 0)) - sum(IF(a.from_warehouse_id = '2', b.transfer_quantity, 0)) as total'))
    ->join('inventory_transfer_details as b', DB::raw('a.id'), '=', DB::raw('b.inventory_transfer_id'))
    ->where([
        ['a.status', '=', 'approved']
        ['b.inventory_or_composite_id', '=', 1]
    ])
    ->get()
```

Comment: i appreciate your help. it is working perfect as i want. is there any scope that we can convert above queroy in laravel query ? or we need to write raw query for laravel ?

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to provide a more generalized answer to this problem: subtracting any `SUM()` from any other `SUM()`.  You could simply do...

```
SELECT Total1, Total2, Total1 - Total2
FROM
    (SELECT SUM(id) Total1 FROM TableA) AS a
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT SUM(id) Total2 FROM TableB) AS b;
```

In your case, the two subqueries, `a` and `b`, would be replaced with the two queries you currently have for calculating sums.